# QGIS Extract values from DSM

Tags: qgis, dem, raster-calculator

I need to create a layer that contains all values between 6 and 9. <= 6 >9. All other values should be 0. 
How can I do this with using the raster calculator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like the following expression which outputs a raster containing the values 6 and 9 (everything else is set to 0):

```
("raster@1" >= 6 AND "raster@1" <= 9) * "raster@1"
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to output a raster only containing boolean values (1 for true; 0 for false), you could just use the expression inside the parentheses (credit to [@mgri](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/87487/mgri)):

```
"raster@1" >= 6 AND "raster@1" <= 9
```

Comment: Beaten by seconds... However, it should also work if you only use the expression between parentheses.

Comment: @mgri - Sorry :). For me, using only the expression inside the parentheses outputs a raster of only 1 and 0 (1 being `True`, 0 being `False`). Does it work for you?

Comment: I get the same result as you and I didn't notice that the OP asked to maintain the values instead of assigning `1` to them. So, you are definitely right! :)

Comment: @mgri - Don't think the OP explicitly mentioned maintaining the values, I just assumed from the context so you could also be right ;)

Comment: Thanks. It works great withe maintaining the values but how can I put the values between 6 and 9 to one and all others to 0?

Comment: As @mgri mentioned, you could just use the expression inside the parentheses =)

Comment: I don´t get it. Can you please write down an example?

Comment: @Andreas - See my edited post.

Comment: @Joseph, really amazing! :)

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks. Is it possible to transform into a shape-file?

Comment: @Andreas - From the menubar: `Raster > Conversion > Polygonize (Raster to vector)`

Comment: @Andreas, remember to accept the answer if it helped you to solve the problem (it will also help future readers).

Comment: Works great. Is there are setting so that only the extracted contours are filled but not the whole layer?

Comment: @Andreas - Most welcome! I think you should ask this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and hopefully others can advise you :)